# IIS 6 how to redirect from http://example.com/* to http://www.example.com/*

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am using asp.net 3.5 and IIS 6.

How can we automatically redirect pages from `http(s)://example.com/*` to `http(s)://www.example.com/*` ?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this with an HttpModule:

```
namespace MySite.Classes
{
  public class SeoModule : IHttpModule
  {
    // As this is defined in DEV and Production, I store the host domain in
    // the web.config: <add key="HostDomain" value="www.example.com" />
    private readonly string m_Domain =
                            WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostDomain"];

    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
      //clean-up code here.
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
      // We want this fire as every request starts.
      context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    #endregion

    private void OnBeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
      var application = (HttpApplication) source;
      HttpContext context = application.Context;

      string host = context.Request.Url.Host;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_Domain))
      {
        if (host != m_Domain)
        {
          // This will honour ports, SSL, querystrings, etc
          string newUrl = 
               context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(host, m_Domain);

          // We would prefer a permanent redirect, so need to generate
          // the headers ourselves. Note that ASP.NET 4.0 will introduce
          // Response.PermanentRedirect
          context.Response.StatusCode = 301;
          context.Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";
          context.Response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
          context.Response.End();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we need to add the module to our Web.Config:

Find the section `<httpModules>` in the `<system.web>` section, it may well have a couple of other entries in there already, and add something like:

```
<add name="SeoModule" type="MySite.Classes.SeoModule, MySite" />
```

You can see this in action here:

- http://doodle.co.uk
- http://doodlegraphics.co.uk
- http://www.doodle-graphics.co.uk

All end up on http://www.doodle.co.uk

Comment: No problem (why is saying thanks so hard? oh, because I have to type an essay in the comments box. I remember when this box took less than 200 characters. Look at it now, demanding lots of characters, and accepting 600 in total - it's bloat and scope creap I tell you!)

Comment: Very good! One thing that didn't work well for me though was if I had Url Rewriting in place. I found changing the newUrl string to the following (in VB) fixed the problem though: **Dim newUrl As String = String.Format("http{0}://{1}", IIf(CBool(context.Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") = "off"), "", "s"), m_Domain + context.Request.RawUrl)**

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the performance will be better if you let IIS handle the redirection.  To do that, create a new web site with the host header set to example.com, and use IIS Manager to configure the redirection.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there's no way to redirect from `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com` - the redirect options for "another website or directory" don't allow for a wildcard on the secure portion (http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score -2):

I think that's best done with DNS.

Comment: Without knowing why the poster wants to do this, it is unlikely that DNS is a suitable approach IMHO. Firstly, the only way I can think of doing it in DNS is with a CNAME which is not a desperately good approach. Secondly, it is highly likely that the poster specifically wants to do the redirection in IIS or in code, given the way the question is tagged.

Comment: @Rob - agreed - generally, the requirement is to have all possible host names resolve to one to ensure that search engines only list one instance of your site - as the OP is asking "how can we redirect doming.com to www.domain.com", I would assume that the DNS is already configured, and both versions are serving the same site.