# redirect in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis-6, atg-dynamo

How would I redirect requests like http://www.mydomain.com/test to the root http://www.mydomain.com in IIS 6.0

Is there any way to do this in IIS itself rather then in the code?

Answer (score 0):

try to see below post that was worked for me when i had faced redirection problem

"[IIS 6 how to redirect from http://example.com/* to http://www.example.com/*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872227/iis-6-how-to-redirect-from-http-example-com-to-http-www-example-com/1872647#1872647)"